# Android and extra validation of certificates

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I want to perform extra validation for SSL connections I make in an android app.
Basically I need to be able to:

- See if the certificate of the remote host I am connected to has Extended Validation (EV) status
- Find out the root certificate authority for the certificate of the remote end. E.g. I want to know if it is a VeriSign certificate or not.

To elaborate a bit more, I am writing a client that needs a high level of security and our organization is using EV certificates from VeriSign on all servers. I want to prevent any compromised certificate authority, or anyone that can fool a certificate authority to forge a certificate for our domain be able to hijack the application.

Is this doable and if so, how? Is there a way to get more information about the certificate of the remote end from a `URLConnection` object or a `HTTPClient` object and so on?

Answer (score 0):

First: you can't possibly 'prevent any compromised certificate authority' from issuing a certificate for your domain. If it is compromised, they can issue whatever they want. What you can do is create a trust store with a limited number of trusted CA certificates, say, VeriSign only. That way, even if an related CA is compromised and issues a cert for your domain, it wouldn't matter since you don't trust it in the first place. That would also take care of second bullet. To have additional checks you need to implement and install your own [X509TrustManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html). Check the [JSSE reference guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) for details.